# How can I use display device in GCP -linux?

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, display

I`m using GCP. Boot Image: c3-deeplearning-tf-1-14-cu100-20191004

Debian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch) (GNU/Linux 4.9.0-11-amd64 x86_64\n)

Error message:
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I wanna use display device.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-instance-virtual-display?hl=en

I saw this docs. But, there is only window-server solution.

Could I get some help for running tkinter in linux-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve it's to use a remote desktop. For this you must follow this steps:

Ssh into your instance

Install the Debian Linux Chrome Remote Desktop package

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
```

Update the package manager data:

```
sudo apt update.
```

Install the package and its dependencies

```
sudo dpkg --install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken
```

Install either [XCFE](https://www.xfce.org/) or [Cinnnamon](https://www.linuxmint.com/)

Connect to the instance using the Chrome Remote Desktop [web site](https://remotedesktop.corp.google.com/access/)

I would advise you to take a look at the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) for further referencing

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally solved this problem by your help.